# How do I send images using discord bot using api

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random
from replit import db
client = discord.Client()
```

> Is this correct?

```
def get_pic():
  pic_url = requests.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search').json()['url']
  return pic_url


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
     return
```

> Is this what I am supposed to do. There is an error when I run it.
> Also, do i need to use an api key in this code?

```
if message.content.startswith('pls catto'):
   pic = get_pic()
   await message.channel.send(content=pic)


client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Test-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 24, in on_message
    pic = get_pic()
  File "main.py", line 10, in get_pic
    pic_url = requests.get('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search').json()['url']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @DrippyDino your getting this, cuz the json that you load is a list get the first element (that will be an dict) then take the url

Answer (score 0):

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/runner/Test-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event await coro(*args, **kwargs) File "main.py", line 24, in on_message pic = get_pic() File "main.py", line 10, in get_pic pic_url = requests.get('api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search').json()['url'] TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Based on this error you submitted. It's pretty self-explanatory.
Simply replace ['url'] with an integer or slice. That index I think should be given to the function as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

i've tried it out

```json
[{"breeds":[],"id":"2qo","url":"https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/2qo.jpg","width":398,"height":500}]
```

Use
.json()[0]['url']

This is because u get as the answer a list with a json

EDIT:

```py
import requests

cattoURL = requests.api.get("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search").json()[0]['url']
print(cattoURL)
```

Comment: Is it supposed to be like that? Cause im still getting an error msg :(
await message.channel.send(json()[0][{"breeds":[],"id":"2qo","url":"https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/2qo.jpg","width":398,"height":500}])

Comment: I've updated my answer with a python code... that does it :)

Answer (score -1):

you can send a file using [discord.File](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.File) Object

and add the file as [keyword](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-are-keyword-arguments-in-python) arg

you can know more about the [send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=send#discord.abc.Messageable.send) function [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=send#discord.abc.Messageable.send)

```py
await channel.send(file=discord.File('path/to/image.png'))
```

EDIT: oh okay you want to send an image from a URL

I didn't test the code, so I am not sure if its works in discord.py 2.0.0

you must download the image

we're going to download the image using  [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) module

and to handle the binary data use
[io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) module.
by [BytesIO](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BytesIO) object

I found this definition about
**StringIO and BytesIO are methods that manipulate string and bytes data in memory. StringIO is used for string data and BytesIO is used for binary data. This classes create file like object that operate on string data. The StringIO and BytesIO classes are most useful in scenarios where you need to mimic a normal file.**

load json data from the [API](https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search) using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```py
import io
import aiohttp
import requests
async def get_json(url):
    rq = requests.get(url)
    return rq.json()

api = "url"
async def image(channel):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        data = await get_json(API) # get json as dict
        async with session.get(data[0]["url"]) as resp: # resp means response
            if resp.status != 200:
                return await channel.send('Could not download file...')
            data = io.BytesIO(await resp.read()) # read bin data
            await channel.send(file=discord.File(data, 'cute_image.png')) # send the a image to the channel
```

Comment: Hi. Where can I get the path file thing

Comment: is this the file path thingy : https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search

Comment: @DrippyDino oh,  you want to send an image from a URL. here I edited. it to match your needs